# Solving a quasi-linear PDE using the method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How does one solve the following equation by the method of characteristics?

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-u^2~\\
$$ with initial data $~u(x,0)=f(x)=x$

What I have so far: we let $V(t)=u(x(t),t)~,$ and $ \frac{dx}{dt}=u$

$ \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=-u^2=-V^2$

so $\frac{dV}{V^2}=-dt$ and from this $V(t)=\frac{V(0)}{1+tV(0)}=\frac{u(x(0),0)}{1+tu(x(0),0)}=\frac{x(0)}{1+tx(0)}~~~$ since $f(x)=x$

now we use ${dx \over dt}=u=V(t)=\frac{x(0)}{1+tx(0)}$ which integrating gives $$x(t)=x(0)+ln(1+tx(0))$$

As far as I know we must now invert this equation for $x(0)=h(x,t)$ and then the solution to the PDE will be $$u(x,t)=f(x(0))=f(h(x,t))$$ however the equation is not invertible for $x(0)$...please could someone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

To solve $x(t) = x(0) + \ln(1 + t x(0))$ for $x(0)$ you can use Lambert's W function: according to Maple,
 $x(0) = W(e^{x(t) + 1/t}/t) - 1/t$.
But if this is homework you're more likely to be expected to leave it in an "implicit" form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, since we haven't covered Lambert's W function, I suspect some sort of implicit analysis is called for. All I seem to have shown however so far, if I'm not mistaken, is that 

$u=\frac{x(0)}{1+tx(0)}$ along the curves $\frac{dx}{dt}=u$

Is there any nice way you would suggest to go about it implicitly?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$u_t+uu_x=-u^2$$
This is what I get from the Charpit-Lagrange equations :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{-u^2}$$
A first characteristic from $-\frac{du}{u^2}-\frac{dt}{1}=0\quad\implies\quad \frac{1}{u}-t=\frac{1-ut}{u}=$constant.
$$\frac{u}{1-ut}=c_1$$
A second characteristic from $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{-u^2}$
$$ue^x=c_2$$
General solution on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$ue^x=F(\frac{u}{1-ut})$$
Condition : $u(x,0)=x$

$x=xe^x=F(\frac{x}{1-0})=F(x)$

Now the function $F$ is determined for any variable $X$ :
$$F(X)=Xe^X$$
We put it into the above general solution where $X=\frac{u}{1-ut}$
$$\boxed{ue^x=\frac{u}{1-ut}\exp(\frac{u}{1-ut})}$$
This is an implicit form of the solution which can be equivalently written with the LambertW function :
$$\frac{u}{1-ut}=W(ue^x)\quad\text{or}\quad u=\frac{1}{t+\frac{1}{W(ue^x)}}$$
But whose forms with special function have not much interest.